# Is there a chance (in QED) that two electrons move from two spacetime points to two other points without interacting?

Tags: electrons, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, interactions, virtual-particles

Is there a "zeroth-order" effect in quantum field theory (QED) that two electrons move from two fixed spacetime points to two other fixed spacetime points without the presence of virtual photons? Of course these spacetime points must be "fairly close" because when they are far apart then it seems obvious that the electrons don't feel eachother's presence so no photons are involved but the electrons travel instead independently from their initial points to their final points in all possible ways. But it their initial points and final points are not too far separated in space is there a zeroth order feynman diagram, i.e., two disconnected lines (representing all possible non-interacting paths)?

Comment: How do electrons feel each other's presence without photons?

Comment: Say you did the experiment that you describe in your question. You prepare two electrons, have them propagate and detect them at their final positions. How  would you tell whether they have interacted or not while they were propagating? It is physically impossible to tell, which is why your question isn't well-posed.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov You could tell they didn't interact when their initial impulses (preparable) were the same as their final impulses (measurable).

Comment: @CosmasZachos They don't, do they?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder oh but what if they exchanged two virtual photons and the effects of the two exchanges canceled each other such that the final momentum happens to be the same as the initial momentum?

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov Then they exchanged two virtual photons. You will say "but how can you tell the difference?" The path with two exchanged photons is second order, while the non-photon path is zeroth order. Don't you have to include both paths in obtaining the total amplitude?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder yeah that’s exactly my point. Only the total amplitude matters, you can’t say “particles haven’t interacted” or “particles interacted with each other”, these statements are meaningless.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov But don't you get the total amplitude by summing over all possible trajectories?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder over all possible diagrams. Some of them don’t contain the interaction, some do. Your question tries to single out the non interacting diagram, but that’s not how QFT actually works — quantum fields evolve according to the sum of all possible diagrams, a single diagram has no physical meaning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123104/discussion-between-deschele-schilder-and-prof-legolasov).

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov Sorry foir that. I accidentally invited you to chat. clear. The diagrams all add up to give the total amplitude. is there a diagram of just two propagating electrons, say two straight lines (this diagram of course involves all possible paths of both electrons)?

Comment: Yes, of course, there is the Feynman diagram with the two straight lines. But as Prof. Legolasov points out, it is meaningless to discuss a single diagram, as ultimately the physical observable (the S-Matrix) is a sum of all of these diagrams.

Comment: @RahulArvind I was curious if this diagram had to be included. In calculating scattering amplitudes (S-matrix), isn't a first order calculation enough?  And do you have to include a zeroth order diagram too?

Answer (score 2):

This question appears to be based on the interpretation of internal Feynman propagators as particles. However, the graphs are representations of terms of a perturbation expansion and only the external legs are particles. Therefore the question actually means, are there cases where the Coulomb interaction between two electrons can be ignored. Of course there are, if the electrons are far enough apart at their closest encounter.

In conclusion and to be clear, there is zero probability that two electrons do not interact. However if they are are far enough apart, their interaction may be neglected.

Comment: As far as you may take them, they will still interact. It may be very small and not measurable but interact they will.

Comment: @Oбжорoв That is why I wrote "ignore".

Comment: fair enough. The OP on the other hand seems to say ask about no interaction at all. A strange question coming from him, if you see how active he is and on what subjects.

Comment: @Oбжорoв I can remember doing calculations with spinors, propagators, vertex factors, etc. but I can't remeber calculating the zeroth order conteribution. It was already enough to consider mosly a second order calculations. Third order maybe once.

Comment: Doesn't each diagram involve taking all possible ways (paths) with one (for first order diagram), two (for second order diagrams), or n interactions (for n-th order diagrams) between an initial state and a final state (in the spacetime representation)? You can also work in momentum space (in which I did the calculations) and take only initial momenta and final momenta. So can't you consider just two external lines? Which are actually just two non-interacting straight lines from initial to final momenta (to which the highest contribution is given by particles traveling straight to the endpoint?

Comment: @Oбжорoв I like your companion reader! Can I download it?

Comment: @DescheleSchilder Yes you can consider two external lines but this does not calculate anything. It just describes two free electrons. Formally you can say that it gives the lowest level of approximation to the process of two, otherwise free, interacting electrons, namely the zeroth order.

Comment: @my2cts Yes, I got it. But thanks anyway! I was indeed considering this as a separate process (which it is, but a virtual one).  And I tried to incorporate this zeroth order in the calculation of two scattering electrons, which by definition have different final momenta. Well there is a chance that you measure two outgoing electrons which have the same momentum as the incoming ones, but this doesn't contribute to the case were one considers two different momenta. It's interesting though that there is a chance to observe real external particles which all have the same momentum.

Comment: @DescheleSchilder yes, of course. You can also correct errors, suggest additions. fwiw I am currently expanding the qft one.